# Hazelcast, logging when something changes in the cache

Tags: java, hazelcast

I'm running Hazelcast embedded in my JVM. I would like some simple logs that will log every time something changes in the cache. Something as simple as `Cache changed: key = value`.

I could write these logs myself, but I would be surprised if this didn't already exist...
However I can't seem to find the option.

Does this sort of logging already exist in Hazelcast?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't one simple config like these `change` event logging or handle another task. Hazelcast has EntryListener interfaces and you can implement according to which events needed. [Here is the documentation](https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/index.html#map-listener).

You can try with following example code snippet.

Create a custom entryListener for what you need.

```
// Your custom entity listener.
@Slf4j
public class MyMapEventLogger implements EntryAddedListener<String, String>,
        EntryRemovedListener<String, String>, EntryUpdatedListener<String, String>,
        EntryEvictedListener<String, String>, MapEvictedListener, MapClearedListener {

    @Override
    public void entryAdded(EntryEvent<String, String> event) {
        log.info("entryAdded: {}" , event);
    }

    @Override
    public void entryRemoved(EntryEvent<String, String> event) {
        log.info("entryRemoved: {}", event);
    }

    @Override
    public void entryUpdated(EntryEvent<String, String> event) {
        log.info("entryUpdated: {}", event);
    }

    @Override
    public void entryEvicted(EntryEvent<String, String> event) {
        log.info("entryEvicted: {}", event);
    }

    @Override
    public void mapEvicted(MapEvent event) {
        log.info("mapEvicted: {}", event);
    }

    @Override
    public void mapCleared(MapEvent event) {
        log.info("mapCleared: {}", event);
    }
}
```

Bind your custom entryListener to yout map after created with `addEntryListener` method.

```
public class ListenerSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HazelcastInstance hz = Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance();

        IMap<String, String> map = hz.getMap("myMap");

        MyMapEventLogger myMapEventLogger= new MyMapEventLogger();
        map.addEntryListener(myMapEventLogger, true);

        // Put, modify and then clear
        map.put("1", "1");
        map.put("1", "2");
        map.clear();
    }
}
```